# Attaching a Kryptoflex cable (Kryptonite) to the frame

Tags: security

I want to attach the double looped cable (bottom) to the frame: it's two metres long, and isn't convenient to wrap around the D-lock, etc. Has anyone done this? Since a clip (top) can't get past the loops on the ends, the only way I can think of is to saw the clip in half and then stick it back together on the cable, but this seems a bit... dumb.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Saw the d clip in half.  Yes that does sound dumb.  How about a picture?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, if understand correctly, the lock is mounted on the down tube as sketched below?

If so, you could try placing the "U" part of the D-lock in the frame mount, hold one loop of the cable on one end of the "U", wrap the cable around the seat post & up over the top tube, then back down to the D-lock & then place the locking mechanism on (also as shown in the sketch below).

Is this in the ballpark? It may keep the cable in tight enough to keep from rubbing on your legs.
[image]

Comment: +1 just for the diagram. How did you generate it?

Comment: Thanks. Done with AutoCAD, just a couple minutes quick CAD work.

Comment: Yeah, that's how it is, just that the d lock is the other way up. I'll try it that way.

Answer (score 0):

1. Unlock the U-lock.
2. Put the loops on the cable onto the U of the U-lock.
3. Clip the U-lock to the frame as normal.

If this is not adequate, use 4:

4. Use a piece of velcro to tie the cable in place to the frame.

Comment: As I said, the D-lock isn't in a good place for me to do that: it's on the hypotenuse of the bike frame and putting the cable there means it bangs into my legs. 

I experimented, and the D-lock couldn't be mounted anywhere else with enough clearance to take it in and out of the bracket. You may be right that 4 is my only option.

Comment: It would help to see what the frame looks like -- most people would the U-lock on the seat tube or a rack if they have one.

Comment: @batman I've found that the best place for the frame mount from kryptonite is on the front fork (partly to do with the oversize tubes on my bike and cable routes). At one point I carried my (independent) cable lock velcroed to a front track on the other side. That worked well but now I put it in a spare bottle holder.

Comment: @Chris H. I too carried my lock (with a cable wrapped around it) on my front fork for a long time with no problems. The unbalanced weight did make it impossible to ride with no hands, but so what. I might add that I really only felt safe with it on the front fork because I also had mud guards & the stay that connected to the eyelet on the fork kept the lock from being able to rotate into the wheel.

Comment: @renesis,I've also got mudguards. I sometimes velcro the lock to the stay to reduce rattling.  Never ridden hands free and any weight moved forwards improves the handling with a toddler seat on the back.